# How to create a regex for a string with different combination of characters

Tags: regex

I want a regex which matches a string with combination of characters with alphabets `a-j/A-J` and even characters `&|()`. 
I have the strings as below examples:

```
(((B&C)&E)|F)|A|D
A&B&C|D|F&E
A|D|(E|(B&(F&C)))
```

The valid characters acceptable in the string are alphabets `a-j` and `A-J`. The other acceptable characters are `&|()`. 
I have to evaluate the string using regex if it contains only the acceptable characters

Comment: add some examples to help us better understand what you need

Comment: to elaborate on @vefthym, please include a [MVCE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: is "abcedfghij&|()" valid? is "abc&|()def"  valid? is "AAA&&&" valid? is "&&" valid?

Answer (score 0):

Smth like this: `[a-jA-J]|\||\&|\(|\)`

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: The above one is not working as it is considered as invalid sequence.Below is the code

String formula = "((A&B)&(AA&C))|C";

    String regex = "[a-jA-J]|\||\&|\(|\)";

    Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(formula);

    if(formula.matches(regex)){

      formulaArr = formula.toCharArray();

    }